# Cannot bind S-PPage in tmux

Tags: tmux

I'm using MobaXTerm to connect to a remote server where I start tmux. I'm trying to bind S-PPage and S-NPage, but with no luck.

I managed to create the binding with the PPage and the NPage (without the shift), also the binding of S-Up and S-Down works well. But not the desired combination. The behavior of hitting S-PPage is the same as hitting PPage outside tmux.

I'm working with tmux 3.4. TERM is xterm. And the relevant bindings currently on my server are:

```
$ tmux list-keys | grep S-
bind-key -r -T prefix       S-Up                   refresh-client -U 10
bind-key -r -T prefix       S-Down                 refresh-client -D 10
bind-key -r -T prefix       S-Left                 refresh-client -L 10
bind-key -r -T prefix       S-Right                refresh-client -R 10
bind-key    -T root         S-NPage                send-keys PageDown
bind-key    -T root         S-PPage                copy-mode -u
bind-key    -T root         S-Up                   copy-mode -u
bind-key    -T root         S-Down                 send-keys PageDown
```

Any idea of why it is not working as desired? Any possible solution?